# Using Image recognition inside a Video with Vuforia and Unity

Tags: image-processing, unity-game-engine, computer-vision, vuforia

I'm trying to do image recognition / tracking inside of video file play from unity.   Is it possible to do image recognition of a video file (not augmented reality) using Vuforia API?

If not, does anyone else have any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to recognize a particular frame in your video stream, most simple but effective solution is matching histograms of your sample frame and frames in your video stream, i don't know whether it can be done using Vuforia API, but if you are interested in implementation of some image processing algorithm the process is quite simple:

1) Convert your sample image in gray (if its a color image).

2) Calculate image histogram for certain number of bin.

3) Store this histogram in a variable.

4) Now run your video file in a loop and extract frames from it, apply above 3 steps and get histogram of same size as of sample image.

5) Find out distance between two histogram using simple some of square, put a similarity threshold there, if distance is less than your threshold frame is quite similar to sample image.

**Another approach may be:**

1) Find out color co-variance matrix from the input sample(if its a color image):

2) to find out it convert your color channel (R,G,B) into column vector and put them column wise in a single variable e.g. [R,G,B].

3) get column wise mean and subtract it with each value of the respected column (Centralize your data around the mean).

4) now transpose your 3 column matrix and multiply it like:

```
         Cov = [R,G,B]^T * [R,G,B];
```

5) above will give you a 3 by 3 matrix.

6) do above for each frame and find distance between cov matrix of sample image and query frame. put threshold to find similarity.

Further extension in above may be finding eigen values of cov matrix and then use them as features for similarity caculation.

you can also try extraction of color histogram rather than a gray scale histogram.

For more complex situation you can go with key-point detection and matching approaches.

Thank You